# Text in CSS is a box - Some properties are for inline content, so I want to know what type of content the text is

Tags: html, css, text, display

It is said that *everything* in CSS is a box, but also the **text**?

If possible also give me official specifications for consultation.

Some properties are **for inline content**, so I want to know what type of content the text is.

For example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

> The vertical-align CSS property sets vertical alignment of an inline,
> inline-block or table-cell box.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: @isherwood Some properties are for inline content, so I want to know what type of content the text is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS 2 described Text as always being contained in an [inline box, an anonymous one if necessary](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css2/#anonymous%E2%91%A0).

> In a document with HTML markup like this:
>
> ```
> <p>Some <em>emphasized</em> text</p>
> ```
>
> the `<p>` generates a block box, with several inline boxes inside it. The box for "emphasized" is an inline box generated by an inline element (`<em>`), but the other boxes ("Some" and "text") are inline boxes generated by a block-level element (`<p>`). The latter are called anonymous inline boxes, because they do not have an associated inline-level element.

However, [CSS3 Display describes things differently](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#text-run). It says that text runs are not boxes, but a different kind of object in the box tree.:

> CSS takes a source document organized as a tree of elements (which can contain a mix of other elements and text nodes) and text nodes (which can contain text), ...
>
> ... it generates an intermediary structure, the box tree, which represents the formatting structure of the rendered document. Each box in the box tree represents its corresponding element (or pseudo-element) in space and/or time on the canvas, while each text run in the box tree likewise represents the contents of its corresponding text nodes.

It should be noted that in the CSS3 scheme, **text is inline content**, even though it is not a box.

The precise details of how inline boxes and text runs are laid out can be found in the [Inline Layout Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#model). Note in particular that all the inline boxes and text runs in a block container are wrapped in a single inline box called the [root inline box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#root-inline-box).

The description of vertical alignment is given in [Transverse Box Alignment: the vertical-align property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#transverse-alignment)

Comment: hi @Alohci, excellent answer +1, in the specification "text run" means the *text itself*, right? I've always been confused as to what exactly it refers to.

Comment: @Coder23 - Basically yes, the text itself. In fact, there's some ongoing debate about [what "text run" precisely means.](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7768#issuecomment-1252103269) For that reason, there is a resolution to change the specification to say "text sequence" instead of "text run".

Comment: Great @Alohci +1 I knew it was confusing. Reading the references you gave me, the text can be an **inline-box** (when *wrapped inside an element*, e.g. a `span`) or an **anonymous inline box** (when *not wrapped in an element*), right, which boils down to **inline content**, right?

Comment: That's what CSS2 says. But CSS3 says no, there isn't an anonymous inline box per piece of text. But both text and inline-level boxes constitute inline content anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alohci +1, that's what I needed to confirm, that the text is inline content. Definitely marked as best answer

Answer (score -1):

Everything is a box in css. It's the way the box reacts that is to be set with the display property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model

Comment: hi @Robbie Bardijn So, is it a inline-level or block-level box?

Comment: Every element has its own default display.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display